# Turned on PC and everything is big Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, display

I got my Linux Mint computer yesterday and everything looked really good and normal yesterday. I turn on my computer today and for some reason that I do not know everything is a lot bigger so much so that some of my folders are going under the panel. I changed monitors and that doesn't seem to work, and I have tried control + 0 that doesn't work. I have tried changing screen resolution but it is already on the normal one. I have tried tinkering with my monitors settings but nothing has worked.

Comment: This used to happen on Ubuntu but they must have fixed it.  My usual approach was to just reboot.

Comment: Sounds like the wrong resolution